# How to check if a maven artifact exists in remote repository

Tags: java, maven, nexus, aether

How can I check a maven artifact is exists or not in a remote repository using Java. Is there any options provided in Aether APIs?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Aether API I am aware of that just does a check. You could just do a HTTP GET of the respective file and abandon the download as soon as it starts though.